# How to properly assemble HLS stream fragments in a single mp4 file in golang

Tags: go, download, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to download an audio HLS stream in golang. My goal is to assemble the fragments into a single mp4 file. At the same time, I'd prefer doing it on the fly, and thus append the fragments to the output file instead of downloading all of them first and then reassemble.

I created a single mp4 file by simply appending all the fragments and served the resulting file using Apache2. Everything seems to work fine as long as I stick to sequential play. In fact, as soon as I try to jump to a certain time, the player simply starts from the beginning. In other words, the resulting file doesn't seem to be seekable.

I also tried ignoring the beginning of each fragment until the `sync byte (0x47)`. I not fully sure about this, but I notice other HLS downloaders doing so. However, I doesn't to help. The file is not seekable.

Here is the snippet of interest (I removed the error handlings to save some lines).

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(out_file, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
defer f.Close()

buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
syncByte := uint8(71) // 0x47

for _, chunk := range mediapl.Segments {
    resp, err := httpRequest("GET", chunk_url)

    // Get the first bytes of the segment (i.e. size of buffer)
    _, err = resp.Body.Read(buffer)

    // Skip what comes before the syncByte
    var bytesW1 int64 = 0
    for j := 0; j < len(buffer); j++ {
        if buffer[j] == syncByte {
            bytesW1, err = io.Copy(f, bytes.NewReader(buffer[j:]))
            break
        }
    }
    // Copy the rest on the segment in the output file
    bytesW2, err := io.Copy(f, resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Printf("%s (bytes: %d + %d)\n", chunk.URI, bytesW1, bytesW2)
}
```

For the sake of completeness, if I download the same stream using ffmpeg and serve the resulting file in the very same way, everything works like a charm.

`ffmpeg -i "https://stream.xyz/index.m3u8" -codec copy output.mp4`

Nevertheless, I'd prefer to implement a solution in pure Go since I'm trying to familiarize with the language.

Any suggestions? :)

**Edit:**
I'm still looking for a solution to this problem, so I asked ChatGPT for an inspiration and I got this code as an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    astits "github.com/asticode/go-astits"
    "github.com/edgeware/mp4ff/mp4"
)

func readTSFile(file string) ([]byte, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    tsFiles := []string{"segment1.ts", "segment2.ts", "segment3.ts"} // Add your .ts files here

    // Create a new MP4 file
    f, err := os.Create("output.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating MP4 file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Initialize MP4 writer
    w, err := mp4.NewWriter(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error initializing MP4 writer:", err)
        return
    }

    var trackID uint32 = 1
    _ = w.AddTrack(&mp4.TrackInfo{TrackID: trackID, TimeScale: 44100})

    for _, tsFile := range tsFiles {
        // Read .ts file
        tsData, err := readTSFile(tsFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading TS file:", err)
            return
        }

        // Demux .ts file
        dmx := astits.NewDemuxerMemory(tsData)
        for {
            data, err := dmx.NextData()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error demuxing:", err)
                return
            }
            if data == nil {
                break
            }
            if data.PES != nil && data.PES.Data != nil {
                // Write to MP4
                if err = w.WriteSample(trackID, data.PES.Header.OptionalHeader.PTS.DTS, data.PES.Header.OptionalHeader.PTS.DTS, data.PES.Data, true); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error writing sample to MP4:", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Close MP4 writer
    if err = w.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error closing MP4 writer:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully created output.mp4")
}
```

While the approach kinda makes sense to me, the code doesn't actually work. For instance, the suggested libraries don't even have such functions :)